# How to copy directories using Ansible on remote machines

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy directories on remote machine using Ansible.

It throws "msg": "Remote copy does not support recursive copy of directory:" error.

below is my ansible playbook.

- name: Copy Juddi depenedent directories
   copy:
     src: "{{ source_vm}}/{{ item }}"
     dest: "{{ destination_vm }}/"
     remote_src: yes
   with_items:
      - "dir1"
      - "dir2"
      - "dir3"

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the synchronize module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html#examples and just replace `copy` with `synchronize`.

Read the example link above. For two directories on one remote host use:

```
- name: Synchronize two directories on one remote host.
  synchronize:
    src: /first/absolute/path
    dest: /second/absolute/path
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Comment: I tried that but it asks for a password to copy the directories. They are on the same   remote machine which I already mentioned in the ansible host file.

Comment: Asked me for a password as well. Guess I'll stick with a Bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the code snippet given by you must work ..

But still you want try a workaround .
You can use the shell module .

Ex:

`- name: Copy the directories to remote server .                                               shell:  |                                                                                        scp -r path/of/file user_name@dns_name:/remote/path                                           delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"`

Answer (score 0):

First: if you want to copy all files and folder to the remote you can use the code below:

```
- name: "Copy Folder"
  hosts: "all"
  vars:
    source_dir: "/path/to/source/directory"
    dest_dir: "/path/to/destination/directory"
  tasks:
    - name: "Copy files and directories"
      copy:
        src: "{{ source_dir }}/*"
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/"
```

---

Second one :

```
- name: "Use Rsync to Copy"
  hosts: "all"
  vars:
    source_dir: "/path/to/source/directory"
    dest_dir: "/path/to/destination/directory"
  tasks:
    - name: "Copy directories"
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ source_dir }}/{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/"
        recursive: "yes"
        delete: "no"
      with_items:
        - dir1
        - dir2
        - dir3
```

If you use sonar or Ansible linter rename module with ansible.builtin. or ansible.legacy.

And the vars can be in a defaults folder or in vars folder.